# Safely and efficiently processing a json web service response in rust

Tags: json, rust, serde, robustness

I have already searched a lot but have so far not found the solution I was hoping for:

Q: What is a proper and efficient way in rust to process a json response from a web service which can by definition not be trusted or relied on 100%.

1. The json fields/structure is known.
2. Values can be empty (or of unexpected content)
3. The processing should be graceful and robust, i.e. forgiving an empty/unexpected value and continue.

The elegant way with `serde` of parsing a string directly into an object like `let p: Person = serde_json::from_str(data)?;` seems not to be an option as it ungracefully fails if one value is not according to expectations. Or is there an option to make it more robust/graceful?

Extracting and validating every single value with `let v: Value = serde_json::from_str(data)?;` and `x = v["text"].to_string()` and capturing every single error individually on the other hand is not a very efficient solution.

Is there a better way to do this efficiently and in a graceful, robust manner that would at least continue when values are missing and could handle empty values or other minor issues gracefully?

PS: Examples from https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/

Comment: Well, what **do** you want to do, when you receive a response that doesn't match schema you expected? 99% of times I would treat it as an error. Deriving `Deserialise` and parsing from string seems like a pretty good option to me.

Comment: Ah well, yes and no. If it's totally out of place, yes. On the other hand parsing it directly into an object already breaks if a value is null. The handling by value at least seems to be able to deal with this after a `.toString` but requires more code.

Comment: If you *expect* that something could be null wrap it in `Option`. Otherwise if it is null, that is a hard error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have deserialization fail and also not fail. You need to pick one or the other. If the API sometimes returns "unexpected content" then that kind of content **is part of the effective schema** and you could use e.g. an [untagged enum](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) to represent it.

For example, what if a field is *usually* a number, but is sometimes a non-numeric string, or is omitted entirely?

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum NumberOrString {
    Number(f64),
    String(String),
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct ApiResponse {
    pub some_value: Option<NumberOrString>,
}
```

Now you can handle any of the three cases:

```
match response.some_value {
    None => { /* Value was null or missing */ }
    Some(NumberOrString::Number(n)) => { /* Value was numeric */ }
    Some(NumberOrString::String(s)) => { /* Value was a string */ }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8763ba5c2c850e7185e9f3fa935afe8c))

The point is that if the API sometimes responds with a structure that is in contradiction with the schema the API documentation describes, then the API documentation is wrong.  You should instead model your schema against what the API actually returns.  You may not know all of the possibilities ahead of time, and so your program *will* sometimes fail to deserialize the response, and that's okay!  When you learn of a new idiosyncrasy, encode it into the schema your program accepts.  The strongly-typed nature of Rust, including its enforcement that `match` arms be exhaustive, means that when you adjust the schema, the compiler will point out all of the places in your program that you need to alter to account for the new possibility.

Comment: Thanks. This is sort of where I ended up as well. While the `serde` parse into object/struct is really nice and handles i.e. even integers out of the box correctly, it also already breaks when a string value is empty.
The bullet proof but also very code intense way seems to be `match` where as for strings `value.toString()` seems to be a reasonable shortcut to capture empty ones with little code.

Comment: @binaryanomaly What do you mean by "it also already breaks when a string value is empty?"

Comment: Should have said: When a field is missing:

`thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("missing field `url`", line: 1, column: 3232)'`

Is there a way to catch that properly while still using the serde parse into struct feature?

Comment: @binaryanomaly As indicated in my answer, if you make the `url` field an `Option<_>` then a missing/null field will get deserialized as `None`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59ed321311f66bfabf6c5f20f5d835cd)

Comment: @binaryanomaly I added a playground link to my answer showing examples of how `Option<NumberOrString>` is able to handle numbers, strings, and missing values.

Comment: Thanks got it and it indeed seems to work with serde parsing into a struct directly as well. On the other hand the effort is now almost the same as when processing every single value of the response.

Comment: @binaryanomaly Well, there are ways you can reuse the code for handling each value, but it depends on the particulars of what that value could be so I can't really make a generalization.

Comment: @binaryanomaly For example: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1895aca8ecaf8a0a5f5928830b47ad6). This gives `Option<NumberOrString>` two extra methods (`into_string` and `into_number`) that can be used to coerce the inner value to a string or number, providing a default value when the value is missing or can't be converted. You could take a similar approach in your code, using the extension trait approach in this playground link, or just using functions.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. It will save a few lines of code and can be reused as a helper function across structs - which is when it will become interesting.